# Selecting first and last records of a join under certain assumptions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a game where each player can place different `in` orders and each `in` order must be followed by one or more `out` orders.
At the end of the game the score of a player is given by the difference between the prices of his first `in` and last `out`.
The definition of the tables for the game is the following, where the sequence of the places is given by the automatic sequence of the inserts.

```
create table prices
(
   sequence int identity(1,1),
   price int
 );    
create table orders
(
   player int,
   sequence int identity(1,1),
   place varchar(30),
   operation varchar(3)
 );
 create table players
(
   player int,
   name varchar(30)
 );
```

I'm doing the following query to compute the score of all the players

```
select cst.name, 
ord_in.place as 'first in' ,
ord_out.place as 'last out' ,
pr_in.price - pr_out.price as 'diff'
from players cst 
left join orders ord_in 
  on cst.player = ord_in.player 
  and ord_in.operation = 'in'
  and ord_in.sequence = (
    select min(sequence) from orders
    where player = cst.player 
  )
left join orders ord_out 
  on cst.player = ord_out.player 
  and ord_out.operation = 'out'
  and ord_out.sequence = (
    select max(sequence) from orders
    where player = cst.player 
  )
left join prices pr_out on pr_out.sequence = ord_out.sequence
left join prices pr_in on pr_in.sequence = ord_in.sequence
```

and the result is fine except for the following case

```
 insert into players (player, name) values (1,'sandra');
 insert into orders (player, place, operation) values (1,'germany','in');
 insert into prices (price) values (10);
 insert into orders (player, place, operation) values (1,'france','out');
 insert into prices (price) values (300);
 insert into orders (player, place, operation) values (1,'italy','out');
 insert into prices (price) values (50);
 insert into orders (player, place, operation) values (1,'spain','in');
 insert into prices (price) values (200);
 insert into orders (player, place, operation) values (1,'russia','out');
 insert into prices (price) values (100);
 insert into orders (player, place, operation) values (1,'belgium','in');
 insert into prices (price) values (80);
```

Why is the last `out` returned as `null`, as shown in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7125d/1)? 
What is going wrong?

Comment: How will you determine the first and last? According to what?

Comment: @Sami yes, I think that is the problem indeed

Comment: @Sami btw why have you deleted the subquery and alias tag? I believe they are relevant anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach for this problem is different based on the point of view.

From a functional/business point of view, I would reply that you have to change the sequence of the inserts without touching the query, because the "game" assumption is that each `in` must be followed by at least one `out`, so the last insert for that player must be a `out` not a `in`.

If I had to fix the query with a minimal change, I would simply add a line in the subquery constraint, by specifying that the `operation` without the alias must be equal to the aliased `operation`.
This is the correct subquery for the `out`. Same fix for the `in`, should it be needed

```
left join orders ord_out 
  on cst.player = ord_out.player 
  and ord_out.operation = 'out'
  and ord_out.sequence = (
    select max(sequence) from orders
    where player = cst.player 
    and operation = ord_out.operation 
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    player,
    name,
    max(case when operation = 'in' and rn_asc = 1 then price end)
        - max(case when operation = 'out' and rn_desc = 1 then price end) diff
from (
    select
        p.player,
        p.name,
        o.place,
        o.operation,
        r.price,
        row_number() over(partition by operation order by o.sequence) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by operation order by o.sequence desc) rn_desc
    from players p
    inner join orders o on o.player = p.player
    inner join prices r on r.sequence = o.sequence
) t
where 
    (operation = 'in' and rn_asc = 1)
    or (operation = 'out' and rn_desc = 1)
group by player, name
```

Comment: Yes, because I've been told that window functions are more performant than grouping, is it true?

Comment: @Giulio: I would expect that this solution should be more efficient than yours with multiple joins. In your db fiddle, this produces a diff of `-290` for player sandra: is this the result that you are looking for?

Comment: But you could do everything with window functions without grouping right? Just to understand, based on which do you choose to go with grouping for a part and window functions for another part? Thank you

Comment: I think you have a typo, a missing `desc`, and it should read ...`order by o.sequence desc) rn_desc`... I guess the correct answer is -90